# Android child fragment not null after removing

Tags: android, android-fragments, child-fragment

I'm trying to run some operations based on whether a child fragment exists. Here is my code:

```
private void addChatFragment() {
    getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.chat_container, ChatFragment.newInstance(),
                    ChatFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

private void removeChatFragment() {
    ChatFragment f = (ChatFragment)getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(ChatFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if(f != null) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }

    Log.v("qwer", "is chat fragment null: " + getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(ChatFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG));

}
```

The problem is my chat fragment is not null after I remove it. Is this expected behavior? And is there a way to completely "remove" to where the fragment is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FragmentTransaction#commit` schedules a removal of the fragment, so it is done asynchronously. `FragmentTransaction#commitNow` does the removal synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentTransaction.commitNow
```

is for api 24 and more if your min api is lower than that you can use popBackStack() after commit().

```
 fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentA);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

Comment: If you're using the support library versions, this is only half true. As long as you're using version 24.0.1 or later, it will work on any API level.